# Двигает или движет?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать "...что двигает людьми в их поступках" или все-таки "движет"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Людьми" в подобнеом контексте - движет. Это давнишний оборот, он сохоранил старую форму глагола.

Answer (score 1):

Глагол двигать(ся) относится к так называемым избыточным глаголам, то есть к глаголам, которые имеют  параллельные формы. Параллельные формы избыточных глаголов могут различаться стилистически и по смыслу.
Слово двигать - многозначное слово. В некоторых  значениях  можно употреблять обе формы,например  поезд двигается и движется (перемещается) . В значении двигаться - начинать движение - только двигаться (поезд двигается - начинает движение). В переносном значении двигать - содействовать развитию чего-либо, побуждать, руководить - употребляется форма движет. Поэтому - людьми движет что-то...

Comment: вы только не сказали, что форма "движет" потихоньку устаревает даже для переносного значения. "Движет людьми (массами)" - едва ли не единсвенное стойкое сочетание на фоне появления (разговорного пока) "двигает учеными", "двигает мыслями" и проч.